# How to change the check box to radio buttons Yes/No in tableselect form api?

Tags: forms

How can I add a radio buttons with Yes/No options instead of the checkbox in the tableselect form (api)?

Here is the code in form.inc on line (3376):

```
$element[$key] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => $title,
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#return_value' => $key,
        '#default_value' => isset($value[$key]) ? $key : NULL,
        '#attributes' => $element['#attributes'],
      );
```

I changed the code like this:

```
$element[$key] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => $title,
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#options' => array(
          '1'   => t('Yes'),
          '0' => t('No'),
        ),
        '#return_value' => $key,
        '#default_value' => isset($value[$key]) ? $key : NULL,
        '#attributes' => $element['#attributes'],
      );
```

When I run it, it shows the form perfectly. But when I click the Submit button it gives me this error:

> "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."

Any help?

Comment: Rule one using Drupal CMS... Never Ever change core files..

Comment: Please explain why you would like to change above code.. Where exactly your field is getting rendered ? Tell me more about the field you would like to change.. There are  many other ways to solve your problem instead of changing core files..

Comment: Hi Anil. Please guide me what is the alternate way to put a radio button instead of the checkbox in the tableselect

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `'#multiple' => FALSE` on the tableselect where you declare it. This will set the tableselect to use radios rather than checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

`#return_value` is not a valid attribute for `#type' => 'radios'`(see [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#radios) ). Try without that line.

And be aware of Anil Sagar comment : "*Rule one using Drupal CMS... **Never Ever change core files***" Means if you need to add radio buttons somewhere, do that in a custom module ...

Comment: It's not at all suggested to alter drupal core...

Comment: Please mind the language you use in stackexchange.. I have given explanation in comment.. :-)

Comment: I have removed the return_value from the code but still it is giving the same "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."